# "as written by" vs. "written by"

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of **as** in **as written by**?

(I've searched everywhere, including many dictionaries, and I've googled it, but there isn't the slightest sign of what that **as** means, and I thought that no definition for **as** was proper in this situation.)

- Is **written by** a shortened form of **as written by**? That is, does it always literally mean **as written by**, but sometimes we shorten it to **written by**? If not, what is the difference?
- Which one is better to use in the following sentence?

> ... my prescription information pamphlets **as written by** [or just plain **written by**] my father.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of "as" is "in the manner or role specified" (see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Adverb)). So "my prescription information pamphlets *as written by* my father" means "(...) in the manner that my father wrote them" (with regard to formulation or other characteristics). This is a formulation that can be used if there is a discussion about the way in which they were written or about their content.

However, "the prescription information pamphlets *written by* my father" is a way of identifying a specific set of documents among a larger set. There may be similar documents written by someone else, but you want to talk only about those written by our father. (Note: I replaced the first "my" with "the". However, "my prescription information pamphlets, which were written by my father, ..." would work in a different syntactic context.)

So "written by" and "as written by" serve different purposes and cannot be used interchangeably.